# ios shortcuts app - create playlist - results do not save to apple music library

Tags: music.app, shortcuts-app

I have attempted to recreate *smart playlist* functionality by using the ios shortcuts app.

I have created a shortcut with 2 steps

- Find *All Music*

  - filters set to find specific songs
  - Get 25 Music Items
- Create playlist *playlist name* with *Music*

If I preview the shortcut, I see that songs are selected as I hoped.

When I open my music library, I see a playlist named *playlist name*, but the songs are not present in the playlist.

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue?

I presume that this is a bug in ios shortcuts or in Apple Music.  What is the best way to report this type of bug?

Answer (score 1):

same problem for me. Really looks like bug issue, but i found how to solve it. Just need to some change 1st part of shortcut, use my screenshot as example. Then it will work. [image]